# Is there way to get grandparent name in sass without variable?

Tags: sass

with varible

```
.comment {
    $hah: ".comment";
    &__item {
        &:hover #{$hah}__right > #{$hah}__bottom {
            height: 3rem;
        }
    }
}
```

can i get grandparent name without varible ?

```
.comment {            this              this
        &__item {      vv                vv
            &:hover .comment__right > .comment__bottom {
                height: 3rem;
            }
        }
    }
```

so i dont have to write .comment class again inside it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no grandparent selector in SASS, however, if you don't want to write the `.comment` selector again, you can store the ampersand in the variable:

```
.comment {
    $hah: &;
    &__item {
        &:hover #{$hah}__right > #{$hah}__bottom {
            height: 3rem;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a [nice article](https://codeburst.io/how-to-do-sass-grandparent-selectors-b8666dcaf961) about this.

Comment: OP specifically said he DIDN'T want to use a variable... (I don't blame him, variables look awful.)

Comment: @EliezerBerlin And yet OP accepted my answer. But feel free to answer with your own solution if you know a better way to do it.

Comment: Fair enough, you're right. Sadly, I couldn't find a solution that was elegant enough to actually improve my code readability, so I've given up.